# Message Box and Form default key behavior

Tags: winforms

I have a DataGridView that the user can search text in.

When the search text box has focus, I'm setting the Search button as the default button, so the user just has to hit the enter key to search. Here's the code

```
private void txtSearchCatsGrid_KeyUp(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        SearchCatsDgV();
    }
}
```

I don't have a default button set for the form. There really isn't a button on the form that I want as the default.

When a search is performed and the result is no records found, I'm opening a message box saying that. The box has just an "OK" button.

The problem is, if the message box opens after a search with no results, if you hit enter, it appears that the search button retains focus and the search re-runs and the message box opens/stays open.

So I guess my question is how do I do the "opposite" of the above code. When the message box is open, obviously I want the Okay button to be the default when it is open and the Enter key is pressed. How do I do that?

Comment: The message box responds to KeyDown.  And closes, now your KeyUp event can fire.  Oops.  Solution is simple, don't use the KeyUp event.  You probably ended up there because you didn't use PreviewKeyDown to tell the control that you want to see the Enter key.

Comment: Use the `KeyDown` event instead of `KeyUp`. You also have no need to set the Button as default (using `button1.NotifyDefault(true);`?), since your TextBox already handles `Key.Enter` on its own. Add `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` before calling  `SearchCatsDgV()` (you should do it anyway).